# native-base icon not showing in Header

Tags: react-native

Here I am using native-base latest version and using all the methods props but still my icons are not appearing in the header

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import {Header,Icon} from 'native-base'

class HomeScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = { header: null }
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'#3q455c',width:"100%"}}>
          <Header
           placement="left"
           leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: 'white' }}
           centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', style: { color: 'white' } }}
           rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: 'white' }}
           />

          </View>
        );

}}
export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

[Here the header function is not showing in the header component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwVRG.png)

Answer (score 20):

To get around this I did:

```
react-native link
react-native run-android
```

and the icons showed.

Comment: This worked!!!. One thing to note here. Command `react-native link` will link all the icon bundles/icon fonts that `native-base` uses into the iOS and Android projects. This makes all of those icon fonts available to the apps.

Answer (score 5):

install react-native-vector-icons

```
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons
```

iOS:

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Android:

Edit android/app/build.gradle ( NOT android/build.gradle ) and add the following:

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

and Use:

```
<Icon
type="MaterialIcons"
name="menu"
/>
```

[document](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, react-native-vector-icons wasn't linked to my project.
So:

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

made the trick for me.

Of course, you must have previously installed react-native-vector-icons module, something like:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
```

Keep coding, and let the code be with you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case after adding below the line in `app/build.gradle` and re-create the build `react-native run-android` the icon will show.

> apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Answer (score 1):

Nirmal Dalmia's answer worked, but if you are using RN >= .60, you do have to install it before linking, as shown:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

This seems to be the case because, starting with .60, RN will autolink your npm dependencies. Since by default `react-native-vector-icons` is embedded within native-base, it won't autolink. I now get an error when running `react-native run-android` telling me not to manually link, but the icons are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code doesn't work.
Here is what I am using:

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import {
  Container, Header, Title, Left, Icon, Right, Button, Body, Content, Text, Card, CardItem
} from "native-base";

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Container style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
            <Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#41b8f4' }}>
              <Left>
                <Button
                  transparent
                  onPress={() => console.log('button')}>
                  <Icon name="menu" />
                </Button>
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Title>Medical</Title>
              </Body>
              <Right />
            </Header>

            <Content padder style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Card>
                <CardItem>
                  <Left>
                  <Icon active name="md-person" />
                  <Text>text</Text>
                  </Left>
                  <Right>
                    <Icon name="arrow-forward" onPress={() =>
                      console.log('right')} />
                  </Right>
                </CardItem>
              </Card>
            </Content>
          </Container>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Native base uses window dimensions for Picker item and this ends in such issues. Add these lines to your Picker. It will solve your issue.

```
style={{ width: '80%' }}
placeholderStyle={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}
textStyle={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}
```

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2630#issuecomment-479847012

Answer (score 0):

The icons in native base are served using react-native-vector-icons package. You don't need to install vector icons as it comes bundled with native base. I had the same problem of icons not showing up. All you need to do is link vector icons to your project.

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

After this, the icons should appear upon reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 0):

Well for some reasons, I had to use this way :

```js
<Icon type='MaterialIcons' name='menu' />
```

In opposition of this way :

```js
<Icon android='md-menu' />
```

Can't find why though. This makes it more complicated to differentiate Android and iOS icons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the required peer dependencies for Native Base 2.x using the `link` command? https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html

This fixed the issue for me:
`npx react-native link`